# Adding another column to a query result - Ruby on Rails Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I have a Product model in which I can make API requests, and shows it as json format. So when I write in the controller for example Product.all, and render as json, (render json: products), it shows perfectly all Products with all columns. However, there is a separated table with the prices, in which I would like to include in the same request, and print as Json. (as adding a new column to the rows in the query result).

It would be something like **Products.all.price_tables_products**

I know its not possible to make such a request, and plus, I need to select only one row from price_tables_products. For example (price_tables_products.last). Do you know the best solution?

product.rb

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :price_tables_products
end
```

price_table_products.rb

```
class PriceTablesProduct < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
end
```

Comment: I don't understand why you have a many to many relation between products and prices.
Also, what is exactly what you want to have rendered?
Probably this could be solved by using a custom serializer, but I want more info as to what your needs are.

Comment: I updated the code for a better relevance. The association is a has_many and belongs_to. It renders something like:

{
id: 22,
name: "Product 2",
},
And I want to render with price that is from another table

id: 22,
name: "Product 2",
price: 2.45,
},

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't fully understand your requirements, but you can do pretty much anything with a custom serializer. You can read about ActiveModel Serializers [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html).

But basically, on your products controller, on the method you want to render your products:

```
class ProductsController < ActionController::Base
  def index
    render json: Product.all, each_serializer: ProductSerializer
  end
end
```

Then, on your `app/serializers` folder you keep the serializer class

```
class ProductSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :description, :created_at, :updated_at, :prices

  def prices
    PriceTablesProduct.where(product_id: object.id)
  end
end
```

On your serializer class you can add all the methods you want to do whatever you want. Even overwrite existing methods so that they are rendered in a specific way.

You can even have your related models rendered by using the well known key words `has_many`, `belongs_to`, etc.

Comment: Perfect. That was exactly what I was looking for. I just had to install gem 'active_model_serializers', even though Im using Rails 5.2.1. Maybe I need to set up something on config. Thanks a lot.